# System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

While creating service bus topic getting below exception in output window. Due to this the subsequent build is failing as vstest.executionengine.exe process is not terminated properly. Had to kill this process to make it work. How to resolve this? Using latest version of servicebus 4.0

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {

        string connectionString = "Sb-connection-string";

        var namespaceManager =
            NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

        if (!namespaceManager.TopicExists("TestTopic"))
        {
            namespaceManager.CreateTopic("TestTopic");
        }

    }

Exception:
System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion.
```

Comment: I use NUnit and XUnit, and haven't seen this. Is this the only test in your suite?

Comment: Should your test(s) really be dependent on external systems like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also repro it on my side. According to the exception, it seems that a thread  did not stop.

[image]

> How to resolve this?

In order to make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion. I add the  `Thread.Sleep(2*1000);` in the end of the code. 
Then it is resolved.

```
   string connectionString = "Sb-connection-string";

   var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

   if (!namespaceManager.TopicExists("TestTopic"))
   {
       namespaceManager.CreateTopic("TestTopic");
   }

   Thread.Sleep(2*1000);
```

[image]

Comment: seems like an option, but is there a more controlled solution, rather than just waiting? 
I am adding this to the build and increasing its time doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Issue I saw the the vstest.executionengine.x86.exe was not closed after the test execution and when a ran the tests twice it starts another process and get the error, the solution I get was to uncheck `Test -> Test Settings called "Keep Test Execution Engine Running"` in Visual Studio